# objAccess.Application.Quit not fully working when trying to close Access database using python

Tags: python, ms-access

HI I am running a MS Access (2010) macro from Python 2.6.5. It's running the macro successfully, but the accdb file is not closing all the way correctly. It shows a .laacdb file along with the .accdb file after my macro runs. I figured doing the CloseCurrentDatabase and Quit statements would do this but they are not. The .laacdb file goes away after I restart computer. Thank you.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
strDbName = "C:\\converter\\MainConverter.accdb"
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('Export_to_PDF')
objAccess.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase()
objAccess.Application.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA we routinely set object variables to `Nothing` to dispose of them.  In Python, try explicitly deleting your `objAccess` variable.

```
del objAccess
```

Sorry, my Python is rusty from disuse, so maybe I got the syntax wrong.  But something like that may help.

Also, I can't recall whether you need a pair of parentheses after the `.Quit` method.  Try it like this just in case:

```
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

In case `objDB` is still holding a reference to the Access application/db, delete it too.

```
del objDB
```

However, if you're not actually using it elsewhere in your real code, just eliminate `objDB` altogether.

Comment: Thanks!
Yea I used objAccess.Application.Quit() and del objDB

Comment: `Sorry, my Python is rusty from disuse` Still you go it in the 1st go ;) + 1 : )